# Python - How to get all Combinations of names from a list: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

I get an error when trying to print the permutation/combination of a user generated list of names.

I tried a couple of things from itertools, but can't get either permutations or combinations to work. Ran into some other errors along the way regarding concatenating strings, but currently getting a: TypeError: 'list' object not callable.

I know I'm making a simple mistake, but can't sort it out. Please help!

```
from itertools import combinations 

name_list = []

for i in range(0,20):
    name = input('Add up to 20 names.\nWhen finished, enter "Done" to see all first and middle name combinations.\nName: ')
    name_list.append(name)
    if name != 'Done':
        print(name_list)
    else:
        name_list.remove('Done')
        print(name_list(combinations))
```

I expect:
1) the user adds a name to list
2) the list prints showing user contents of list
3) when finished the user inputs "Done":
    a) 'Done' is removed from the list
    b) all the combinations of the remaining items on the list printed

Comment: Shouldn't it be `combinations(name_list, r)` instead of `name_list(combinations)`?

Comment: Are you sure you want ```combinations``` and not ```permutations```? If you want them combined you need to specify how many items each combination will have.

Comment: Thanks! All of this information is helpful! I was able to solve the problem. I ended up using permutations and specifying that I wanted all the permutations in groups of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutations and combinations are two different beasts. Look:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations,combinations
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> pprint(list(combinations(l, 2)))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> pprint(list(permutations(l)))
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd', 'c'),
 ('a', 'c', 'b', 'd'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd', 'b'),
 ('a', 'd', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'd', 'c', 'b'),
 ('b', 'a', 'c', 'd'),
 ('b', 'a', 'd', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c', 'a', 'd'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd', 'a'),
 ('b', 'd', 'a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'd', 'c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a', 'b', 'd'),
 ('c', 'a', 'd', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b', 'a', 'd'),
 ('c', 'b', 'd', 'a'),
 ('c', 'd', 'a', 'b'),
 ('c', 'd', 'b', 'a'),
 ('d', 'a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'a', 'c', 'b'),
 ('d', 'b', 'a', 'c'),
 ('d', 'b', 'c', 'a'),
 ('d', 'c', 'a', 'b'),
 ('d', 'c', 'b', 'a')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

for use combinations , you need to give the r as argument.this code give all combinations for all numbers(0 to length of list),

```
from itertools import combinations 

name_list = []

for i in range(0,20):
    name = raw_input('Add up to 20 names.\nWhen finished, enter "Done" to see all first and middle name combinations.\nName: ')
    name_list.append(name)
    if name != 'Done':
        print(name_list)
    else:
        name_list.remove('Done')
        break

for i in range(len(name_list) + 1):
    print(list(combinations(name_list, i)))
    print("\n")
```

Comment: You need to start range at 1.